# What are pros and cons of using vendor-specific extesions not included in W3C specifications?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, w3c, web-standards

**I edited my question**

> What is a vendor specific extension?
>
> A vendor specific extensions can start
> with a “-” (dash) or a “_”
> (underscore), usually followed by an
> abbreviation of the company or the
> browser project the extension is
> specific for, f.i. “-moz-” for Mozilla
> browsers, or “-webkit-” for WebKit
> based browsers. This vendor specific
> prefix is followed by the property
> name. A good example of this is
> -webkit-border-radius, or -moz-border-radius.

**IE has 3 things:**

1. .htc file support (same as javascript)
2. css expressions (also a form of javascript)
3. some IE only [xhtml](http://webdesign.about.com/cs/htmltags/a/aa012300a_3.htm) and [css
   properties](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/09/08/microsoft-css-vendor-extensions.aspx)

**[Web-kit](http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/general/webkit_css_styles) and [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions) also have some of their own CSS properties.**

Some others links:

http://webdesign.about.com/cs/htmltags/a/aa012300a.htm

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vendorspecific#

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200911/vendor-specific_extensions_are_invalid_css/

http://www.css3.info/vendor-specific-extensions-to-css3/

**My questions:**

Could we face any problem now or in future if we use non-W3C standard CSS?
Examples:

1. If I have a jquery code and vendor-specfic CSS code for the same solution, which should i use? Using a vendor-specfic CSS solution will work if JS is disabled but the page will not pass W3C validation. If I use the JS solution the page will be passed in validator. An example would be for making a round corner.
2. Will it hurt in any sense if the site is not fully W3C validated due to using vendor-specific properties? Should I avoid vendor-specfic things as much as possible to get good cross-browser and platform compatibility such as for PC, MAC, iPhone, other mobiles?
3. Should I choose a JS solution over a vendor-specfic CSS property if I have a solution in both for the sake of passing the W3C validation? If I choose the JS solution every time the site will not work well on mobile browsers. Is it alright to leave it alone if the W3C validation is giving an error for vendor-specific extensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The principle you should try to follow, when considering vendor specific extensions, is [progressive enhancement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/). The basic idea is that you should design your site to work for as many people as possible; design it to work in plain HTML 3.2, on a terminal client, with no JavaScript, CSS, or any sort of vendor specific extension.

Then, you add on style and functionality, using more advanced standards that not all browsers support, using designs for visual media, using CSS and JavaScript which may be disabled, and finally, using vendor-specific extensions, which are not at all supported by other browsers. But because you first started designing given a common set of functionality that everyone supports, you don't need the extra functionality from the new features for the site to work; it will continue working in old browsers, with old features, as the new features were added as enhancements, not as something essential for your site to work.

So, you shouldn't rely on these vendor-specific extensions, but use them as enhancements. If for some reason, you do rely on them—if your product cannot function without an extension available on a particular browser—then it may be worth using one. But in that case, your future is inextricably linked to that browser. If it falls by the wayside, you're [SOL](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=S.O.L.). If it winds up being used only in Korea, and your product is in German where another browser is the dominant one, again, you're SOL.

Now, there are different sorts of vendor-specific features to choose from when making these decisions. There are some features that will always be specific to a particular vendor; features that are not applicable on other platforms, or which have been proposed to a standards body and that entire approach has been rejected. These features are ones that you want to use very, very judiciously.

There are other features which are on the standards track. They are in a current CSS 3 draft, they are implemented in two or three different browsers almost compatibly. These features are ones that you may be able to begin relying on, if your user base all support them, as they are pretty certain to be implemented by a majority of major browsers (used by a majority of potential users) at some point in the future.

So, in sum, I would say that you should feel free to add effects to your pages that are supported only in an individual browser. But you shouldn't rely on these, unless you have a good reason to believe that they will soon be supported by all of the major browsers. The current state of HTML supported by the major browsers can do quite a lot; try working within the current standards, and functionality common between the browsers, as much as you can, while keeping in mind that adhering to standards isn't paying the bills, it's providing functionality, and a certain amount of style, that is.

As a direct answer to your question, about the pros and cons of vendor specific extensions:

#### Pros

- Get access to features that may become widespread sooner
- Provide better value to your customers
- You can do really cool, fun stuff
- Help encourage implementers of other browsers, and people working on standards, that this feature is a good idea

#### Cons

- The feature may go away, and never turn up even in later versions of the same browser
- If you rely on such extensions, you may limit your user base severely
- The feature may change significantly before released, leading to broken pages, or some new sniffing mode that is really hard to figure out.

As to whether you should use a JavaScript based approach or the CSS extension approach, that's a judgement you should make on a case by case basis. If you have been able to follow the principles of progressive enhancement, they are both fine to use. As long as it is not an essential feature of your site, or you find alternative ways of doing the same thing for all of the major browsers, I would say that CSS would be preferred over a JavaScript solution, as it will generally be smaller and faster loading.

Something to consider about validation is that while it's generally a good idea to ensure your HTML validates (though not always essential; see [Google](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) for example, where they consider minimizing download size to be more important than validating), validation failures due to vendor-specific properties in your CSS are less critical. In CSS, unknown properties are defined to just be ignored, so even if it doesn't validate because you use a vendor specific property, you know how it will behave in browsers that don't support that property; they will just ignore it. And if you've followed the approach of progressive enhancement, then your site should still work fine if those properties are ignored, meaning that there's no negative impact other than your site looking a little bit less nice.

Answer (score 5):

Uhh... that they won't work on other browsers...?

Answer (score 2):

Adherence to standards is considered **best practice** throughout industry because it leads to predictability and interoperability.

This applies across *all* industries, not just the creation of web content.

If we're going to agree that the W3C is the *standards-making* body for the Web, we should follow the guidelines they set down.

This means not relying on proprietary extensions, regardless of who introduces them.

Comment: While that ethic might fly in a boxy MBA enterprise environment where creativity is frowned upon, design as an art isn't really about adherence to standards. The CSS based animation features in current WebKit builds that absolutely trounce all JavaScript equivalents in terms of performance and in terms of the amount of code written are more than enough reason to disregard the standards wherever you can.

Comment: @NSD: in my book, **as long as your site is still usable without those animations**, it's fine to use those proprietary features.

Comment: If you creatively build a site that will only work in WebKit browsers, then I'd hope you'd creatively work for a competitor of mine.

Comment: You needn't worry. I don't build sites for anyone. I was speaking from my perspective, as an Engineer, where compliance with standards is considered important. I recognise that web developers shy away from standards, because the 'standards' are only guidelines, and there's a kind of *arms race* going on to keep the browsing public entertained and coming back. I think the OP, while *deeply curious* about these things is not a developer, either.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your site strictly and exclusively targets Windows + IE users, and you're happy to lose all traffic from Firefox users, Mac ones, ones with iPhones or Blackberries or Android devices, and so on, using any proprietary IE extensions is incredibly myopic.  Microsoft just agreed with the EU to offer a "palette of browsers" for users' choice as default browser in the near future, so one can imagine that the percentage of Windows users sticking with IE as their default or only browser can likely decrease in the future.

Using proprietary extensions from Firefox is almost as myopic -- you'll have a hard time convincing all visitors to switch to FF for your site (from IE, Safari, or whatever else they prefer), and, although the range of devices on which you can install FF is broader than those on which you can install IE, you're **still** cutting off devices such as iPhones and Android, a segment of the market that's growing *much* faster than "traditional PCs".

Comment: u mean i should use W3C standatds as much as possible?

Comment: Of course not. Your site should be as non-standard as possible. The more standard it is, the more browsers it will work with.

Comment: But this is really a problem with the *browsers*, not the standards ;-D