# Set charset meta tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, character-encoding, epiceditor

There's a bug I'm trying to track down here: https://github.com/OscarGodson/EpicEditor/issues/184#issuecomment-8805982

Based on all the information it *seems* like it's because the browser is defaulting to the user's native charset (in this case, `ISO-8859-1`) and not `UTF-8` like on my machine and others in the US. I'm guessing that a fix is to use HTML to force the encoding to `UTF-8` with:

```
 <meta charset='utf-8'>
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='Type=text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

However, the JS isn't working. In the first example:

```
charsetMetaTag = self.editorIframeDocument.createElement('meta');
charsetMetaTag.charset = 'utf-8';
self.editorIframeDocument.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(charsetMetaTag);
```

I just get back the following injected into the DOM:

```
<meta>
```

And in the 2nd example the `http-equiv` isn't being set:

```
charsetMetaTag = self.editorIframeDocument.createElement('meta');
charsetMetaTag['http-equiv'] = 'Content-Type';
charsetMetaTag['content'] = 'text/html; charset=utf-8';
self.editorIframeDocument.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(charsetMetaTag);
```

I get back the following HTML:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Yes, I need to do this dynamically as im dynamically creating the iframes.This may not even be the issue, but this is what it's looking like. The only "hack" i can think of is somehow using innerHTML...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't set the charset content attribute by setting the charset property because they don't reflect each other. In fact there is no property that reflects the charset content attribute.

The http-equiv content attribute is reflected by the httpEquiv property so

```
 charsetMetaTag['httpEquiv'] = 'Content-Type';
```

would create the meta element correctly.

But none of this matters. The character set is established by the parser, so constructing the meta element in JavaScript after the HTML has been parsed will have no effect on the character set of the document at all.

Comment: Doesn't it matter for dynamically generated HTML that is yet to be parsed?

Answer (score 1):

As Alohci said, creating charset-related meta tags from JS won't have much effect on the current page.

In my usecase, I need to be able to serialize the current page as a string and save it to some backend. Appending a missing charset meta tag (if not present) is useful for such an usecase.

As a side-node, don't forget that the charset metatags should be **at the beginning of**  according to the HTML5 spec. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987065/what-are-best-practices-to-order-elements-in-head). This simple detail has lead to an important bug in my app :)

You should rather use:

```
document.head.insertBefore(charsetMetaTag,document.head.firstChild);
```

Comment: Can you explain what this code does? You say before that *"creating charset-related meta tags from JS won't have much effect on the current page."* So what is the purpose of your code?

Comment: @quark67 it's in the text: it puts the charset tag first child in head tag

Answer (score 1):

I agree with both @alohci and @sebastien-lorber answers.

But just addressing your orginal issue with just getting

```
<meta>
```

using the setAttribute method

```
charsetMetaTag.setAttribute("charset", "UTF-8");
```

and following @sebastien-lorber suggestion, will output

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

as first child element of head

Comment: indeed that's the result, but indeed no effect on the current page.

Answer (score 0):

the meta tag is part of a document, and seems to rule the parsing of that document.

hence, if you wish your iframe src to be parsed as utf-8, it should be part of the document in that iframe.

javascript will run in a document after it has already been parsed.

it would still be interesting to see how dynamically loaded js and style may use a later declared charset.