# generating HTML in WebExtension results in `this.mDialog is null` and `can't access dead object`

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon-webextensions, createelement

Using a [WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions), I am trying to programmatically generate an HTML file like this:

```
<html><head><meta><title>example</title></head><body><p>Hello, world!</p></body></html>
```

and then download it using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066452/easiest-way-to-open-a-download-window-without-navigating-away-from-the-page). (Background: [I am generating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197847/preserve-charset-attribute-of-meta-tag-in-html-blob)
a [client-side redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page).)

Here's my `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Download HTML",
  "description": "Generates an HTML file and downloads it",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Download HTML"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

and here's my `background.js`:

```
function downloadHTML(tab) {
  console.log('Begin downloadHTML()')
  function generateHTML(title) {
    var newHTML = document.createElement('html');
    var newHead = document.createElement('head');
    var newTitle = document.createElement('title');
    newTitle.text = title;
    var newMeta = document.createElement('meta');
    var newBody = document.createElement('body');
    var newPar = document.createElement('p');
    var newText = document.createTextNode('Hello, world!');
    newPar.appendChild(newText);
    newBody.appendChild(newPar);
    newHead.appendChild(newMeta);
    newHead.appendChild(newTitle);
    newHTML.append(newHead);
    newHTML.append(newBody);
    return newHTML;
  }
  // Now make an anchor to click to download the HTML.
  var tempAnchor = document.createElement('a');
  var myHTML = generateHTML(tab.title);
  var HTMLBlob = new Blob([myHTML.outerHTML], {type: 'text/html'});
  tempAnchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(HTMLBlob);
  var filename = 'index.html';
  tempAnchor.download = filename
  tempAnchor.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(tempAnchor);
  tempAnchor.click();
  document.body.removeChild(tempAnchor);
  console.log('End downloadHTML()')
}
// Add downloadHTML() as a listener to clicks on the browser action.
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(downloadHTML);
```

I've run the extension on this page:

http://info.cern.ch/hypertext/WWW/TheProject.html

When I do so, the browser console confirms that the function runs from start to finish.

```
Begin downloadHTML() background.js:2:3
End downloadHTML() background.js:31:3
```

However, there is no download prompt, and I receive this error message:

```
TypeError: this.mDialog is null [Learn More] nsHelperAppDlg.js:173:5
```

The "Learn More" just links to "TypeError":

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unexpected_type

When I debug the extension, I find these messages instead.

```
Webconsole context has changed

TypeError: can't access dead object [Learn More] accessible.js:140:5
```

The "Learn More" links to information about dead objects.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Dead_object

I'm guessing that the HTML elements are not persisting between calls to `document.creatElement()`. I've tried moving the body of `generateHTML()` out into its parent function, but that did not help.

How can I make sure the HTML persists? I don't want to modify the actual tab HTML, I just want to access the tab's title (and eventually URL). I looked at the Web Storage API, but I want to store HTML, not key-value pairs.

I am running Firefox version 63.0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an actual DOM in order to click it.

Anyway ... it can be a lot simpler

```
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(downloadHTML);

function downloadHTML() {

  // download to file, downloads string (not DOM)
  const data = '<html><head><meta><title>example</title></head><body><p>Hello, world!</p></body></html>';
  const blob = new Blob([data], {type : 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'});
  const filename = 'something.html';

  // both are fine: chrome.downloads.download or browser.downloads.download
  // requires "downloads" permission
  browser.downloads.download({
    url: URL.createObjectURL(blob),
    filename,
    saveAs: true,  // pops up a Save As dialog, omitting it will save the file to the Downloads folder set in Firefox Options
    conflictAction: 'uniquify' // renames file if filename already exists
  });  
}
```

If you want to show an actual page on `browserAction` then it would be easier to set a `"default_popup"` in `manifest.json`

Comment: The HTML is just for illustration; I do actually need to generate a different one depending on the tab, and just concatenating strings could lead to issues with encoding and escaping. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197847/preserve-charset-attribute-of-meta-tag-in-html-blob

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver The code was also an example. It should be adapted to the desired use.