# HTML Standard for Head layout?

Tags: html, standards, html-head

I've seen many different layouts, and I'm not sure if there is a standard.

Is there a proper way to order `<title>`, `<meta>`, `<link>`, and `<script>` elements in the head?

I'm fairly new to web development and would like to make good habits from the start if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are best practices to order elements in <head>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987065/what-are-best-practices-to-order-elements-in-head)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, You can add title, meta, link, and script anywhere you want in head section.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below example.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>HTML Site title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="description here">
  <meta name="author" content="site author">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
your code here
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [W3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML#Stop_right_there.21_Inline_CSS_and_JavaScript_is_not_too_clever.21) should be:

- Meta charset
- Title
- Stylesheet
- JavaScript Files

Comment: The site you have linked to is MDN not W3C. And the page says nothing about a specific order.