# What is performance-optimized order of assets in HTML head?

Tags: javascript, html, css, page-load-time, core-web-vitals

I have following assets:

- Preloaded local javascript - `<link rel="preload" as="script" href="my.js">`
- Local javascript - `<script type="text/javascript" src="my.js" async defer>`
- DNS-Prefetch of CDN domain - `<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//my.cdn.com">`
- Preconnect of remote javascript - `<link rel="preconnect" href="//consentscript.tld">`
- Remote javascript - `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://remote.server/my.js" async defer>`
- Inline javascript - `<script>myFunc...;</script>`
- Inline styles - `<style>body{color:black;}</style>`

Empirically, I realized that the order of these assets, as they are listed in the HTML head, influences the loading speed of the page and the Core Web Vitals metrics.

Could somebody point me to the performance-optimized order of asset placement in the HTML head? A link to documentation would help me too.

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987065/what-are-best-practices-to-order-elements-in-head

Comment: On the first view is the thread you shared mostly about w3c rules than about performance. But nevertheless thank you, in parts it will be helpful.

Comment: as I feared - the thread is about w3c and not about performance - not really helpful :(

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Get your `head` straight](https://speakerdeck.com/csswizardry/get-your-head-straight) by Harry Roberts, summarized in [this Smashing Magazine post](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/09/css-head-tag/) and [CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/newsletter/270-wheres-your-head-at/) for guidance and tools to help you optimize the `<head>` contents.

Comment: Do you probably know, Stoyan Stefanov of phpied.com offered some years ago a test tool to test performance of different orders of different assets (local and remote CSS, JS, images, and fonts) . I can't find it anymore :(

Comment: No sorry I'm not sure about that tool

Comment: if interesting - Patrick Meenan recommended a similar, pretty the same tool: https://cuzillion.com/